# How to find instances in Sequelize by querying a key/value in an array of dictionaries

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I'm migrating a web app database from Mongoose to [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) (so that I can use MySQL). I'm looking for the Sequelize equivalent of this Mongoose query:

```js
models.Instance.find({ "events.id": eventID })
```

The query enabled me to find an Instance that contained an event (inside the events array) with id == eventID.

I've tried the following but it doesn't give the required result:

```js
models.Instance.findAll({
    raw: true,
    where: {
      "events.id": eventID
    }
  })
```

The Instance model in Sequelize looks like this:

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Instance = sequelize.define('Instance', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    events: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
    }
  });

  return Instance;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which involved switching to a PostgreSQL database, as this has support for the [JSONB data type](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#jsonb).

After changing the data type in my instance model -

```js
    events: {
      type: DataTypes.JSONB,
    }
```

I used this code for my query:

```js
var models  = require('../../models');
const Op = models.Sequelize.Op;

models.Instance.findAll({
  raw: true,
  where: {
    events_current: {[Op.contains]:[{
        id: eventID
      }]
    }
  }
})
```